# Append pages to existing Postscript file with gnuplot

Tags: linux, plot, gnuplot

I want to save some plots that I obtain from different gnuplot programs, ran at different time to go on to the same postscript. At present, if I set the terminal to postscript and give an output file like this:

```
set terminal postscript eps size 19.2,10.80 enhanced color \
    font 'Helvetica,20' linewidth 2
set output 'temp.eps'
```

gnuplot overrrides the existing file `"temp.eps"` and plots the new plot in a new file. How can I make it to append another page to the existing postscript?

Comment: Gnuplot cannot merge postscript files. Possibly you can find some command line tool to which you can pipe the output which then merges the current plot with previous ones, like `set output "| mytool old.ps -"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use latex to do this. The following tex file (which I have named `test.tex`) will embed your eps files (here `temp.eps` and `temp2.eps`) into the same PS file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{temp}

\newpage

\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{temp2}

\end{document}
```

For which you need to run

```
latex test.tex
dvips test.dvi
```

which generates a PS document called `test.ps` which contains `temp.eps` in the first page and `temp2.eps` in the second page.

Comment: This is what I am doing as of now, combining multiple postscripts together. I was wondering if gnuplot has some option to do it automatically.